# How to prevent Sodium Hydroxide (Catalyst) from reacting with the Formic Acid (product) after electrolysis is done

Tags: plastics, carboxylic-acids

So,

I am trying to create Formic Acid from PET and to break the ester bonds before electrolysis, I am planning on using water and sodium hydroxide. I was told that if I take this Plastic-Sodium Hydroxide-Water solution and electrolyze it with my gold diode, I should be able to get formic acid, as the Sodium Hydroxide is supposed to act as the catalyst. My only concern is that once the Formic Acid is formed, it would get neutralized by the Sodium Hydroxide catalyst. How do I prevent this?

Comment: You cannot prevent it in the described scenario.

Comment: It will also react with the terphthalic acid product

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may be able to reduce the lose due to a neutralization reaction with a carefully constructed electrolysis cell.

Try following, for example, the prototype provided in the electrolysis of aqueous $\ce{NaCl}$ as a source of $\ce{NaOH}$ along with $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{Cl2}$ gas. In particular, per this [educational reference](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zcr2pv4/revision/2), note the use of a **diaphragm** to limit product mixing.

To quote the source on actual products collected for commercial use:

> The three products of the electrolysis of concentrated sodium chloride solution have important uses in the chemical industry:

> - hydrogen is used as a fuel and for making ammonia

> - chlorine is used to sterilise water supplies, and to make bleach and hydrochloric acid

> - sodium hydroxide is used to make soap, paper and bleach

Note, during and after the electrolysis, the diaphragm limits further unwanted reactions.

See if you can make a related design structure work in your case.